# Why is my WordPress login credentials missing, but work with WooCommerce?

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, users, account

I have a constant issue where my login credentials are not found when trying to enter WordPress.org. Password reset option is not possible as my username and email address is not found. Yet, I am still able to access WooCommerce, that utilizes the same login credentials - as it is required to create the WooCommerce account.
This is a progressive and long time issue that I have had to resolve over and over again by creating a new WordPress account. This is not wise, as it is not linked to my WooCommerce account and causes issues when trying to report issues (like this).
To validate my issue, I have even reviewed account creation welcome emails I have received from WordPress that clearly show my account name and email. I am running out of password ideas...

Comment: Is your WooCommerce account not the same account you log in to WP? There should be no difference between the two, there is no separation between WP and WooCommerce users, they're one and the same, work the same, stored the same. When you say WordPress is this self hosted or are you a WP.com user? Keep in mind this site is for programmers with technical questions, it isn't a support forum

Comment: Or do you mean actually logging into the woocommerce.com and wordpress.org websites, not your own installed WordPress instance? You'd have to ask them about this sorry.

Answer (score 1):

[wordpress.org](https://wordpress.org/) does not share accounts with [woocommerce.com](https://woocommerce.com/), and neither account is the same account that would be used to log into any self-hosted website that you have.

[woocommerce.com](https://woocommerce.com/) and [wordpress**.com**](https://wordpress.com/) *do* share accounts, but again, neither of these are used for [wordpress**.org**](https://wordpress.org/).

For more information on the difference between [wordpress.org](https://wordpress.org/) and [wordpress.com](https://wordpress.com/), see [this support article](https://wordpress.com/support/com-vs-org/).

Comment: +1 but I think you can use your wordpress.com password on your own site, with [Jetpack Security](https://jetpack.com/features/security/secure-authentication/) - it looks like there's an oAuth endpoint for it somewhere.

Comment: Thank you, but your assumption is that I have different account information used for each of these accounts. That is not correct. Being that all rely upon a user created ID, email address and password - if all are the same, then that makes your response moot. The experience I am having, when I attempt to log into any one of these accounts it demands I use my "wordpress" credentials. A box appears on the all white page with the related logo and request I enter my email OR user ID. No matter what I enter, it is declared invalid.

Comment: Your username and password on WordPres.org and WordPress.com are _not the same thing. If you have not created an account on WordPress.org, then you cannot log into WordPress.org. It's that simple. Having a WordPress.com or WooCommerce.com account will not get you into WordPress.org.